# Remove default "textLabel" in UITableViewCell

Tags: ios

I have subclassed UITableViewCell for a custom cell view along the lines as follows:

```
@interface CustomCell : UITableViewCell

@property (nonatomic, strong) IBOutlet UILabel *customTextLabel;

@end
```

Is there a way to get rid of the default "textLabel" such that the following code will fail:

```
CustomCell *cell = (CustomCell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"CustomCell"];

[cell.textLabel setText:@"whee"];
```

I want to restrict usage such that the only text label that can be set is my "customTextLabel".

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can override the getter for text label returning (a) your label or (b) nil:

```
-(UILabel*) textLabel {
    return myLabel; // or perhaps return nil
}
```

This will prevent users of your derived class from accessing the label of the base cell type.

Comment: I see. If I returned nil, the compiler would not be smart enough to catch an error if a user accidentally did something like [customCell.textLabel setText:@"blah"] though, correct?

Comment: Correct. This will go through to runtime, at which point it would be ignored as sending a message to nil.